# C# Rx Observable producing random results

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

Consider the following program;

```cs
class Program
{
    static IObservable<int> GetNumbers()
    {
        var observable = Observable.Empty<int>();
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
        {
            observable = observable.Concat(Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Producing {i}");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return i;
            })));
        }

        return observable;
    }

    static async Task LogNumbers(IObservable<int> observable)
    {
        var subscription = observable.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"Consuming {i}"));
        await observable;
        subscription.Dispose();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LogNumbers(GetNumbers()).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It produces the following output

```
Producing 1
Producing 1
Producing 2
Consuming 1
Producing 2
Producing 3
Consuming 2
Producing 3
Producing 4
Consuming 3
Producing 4
Producing 5
Consuming 4
Producing 5
Producing 6
Consuming 5
Producing 6
Producing 7
Consuming 6
Producing 7
Producing 8
Consuming 7
Producing 8
Producing 9
Consuming 8
Producing 9
Producing 10
Consuming 9
Producing 10
Finished
```

It writes out two of every "Producing x" statements and one "Consuming x" statement. Why does it do this? Why does it never write out the expected final "Consuming 10" statement?

Comment: You are concat (observable.Concat) data together an not clearing the observable.

Comment: A good rule of thumb, where possible, is "don't mix your monads". This applies to using tasks and Rx at the same time. Instead of `Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.Run(() => i))` you should simply use `Observable.Start((() => i)`. Try to stay in the Rx world as much as possible. It doesn't solve your issue here, but it will make your Rx code more robust.

Comment: @Enigmativity understandable, thanks. I just wanted to add some delay to reproduce the problem. If it is too fast the second problem doesn’t happen. My actual code is nothing like this, but I will be fired if I post that 

Comment: @Steztric - Use `Observable.Delay` to add a delay. :-)

Comment: @Enigmativity great tip, thanks

Comment: @Steztric - Like this: `Observable.Return(42).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))`.

Comment: @Steztric - In your code you should use this: `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Select(i => i + 1).Do(i => Console.WriteLine($"Producing {i}")).Take(10)` - that replaces `GetNumbers()` entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting two copies of the Producing lines because you are subscribing twice.  Most likely, you are not getting the consuming 10 because the first subscription is being cancelled when the second subscription ends.  I would not be surprised if you sometimes did get the Consuming 10, just because the Tasks run in a different order that time.

```
static async Task LogNumbers(IObservable<int> observable)
{
    //This is the first subscription
    var subscription = observable.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"Consuming {i}"));

    //This is the second subscription
    await observable;

    subscription.Dispose();
}
```

The way your `GetNumbers` function is written, each subscription to the observable will trigger its own set of 10 tasks to run, and thus its own set of outputs.  The first subscription also monitors the produced values and outputs a Consuming line.  The second subscription does nothing with the produced values, since you did not use the value of `await observable`, but does cause a second set of tasks to run.

You could eliminate the second subscription by either using `Publish().RefCount()` on the parameter to LogNumbers or by instead using a TaskCompletionSource and marking it complete from the OnError and OnComplete functions you currently aren't using in the first subscription.  Those would look something like this:

```
static async Task LogNumbersWithRefCount(IObservable<int> observable)
{
    observable = observable.Publish().RefCount();
    var subscription = observable.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"Consuming {i}"));
    await observable;
    subscription.Dispose();
}

static async Task LogNumbersTCS(IObservable<int> observable)
{
    var t = new TaskCompletionSource<object>()
    var subscription = observable.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"Consuming {i}"),
                       ex => t.TrySetException(ex),
                       () => t.TrySetResult(null));
    return t.Task;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Gideon nailed the issue for you, but as I started putting some hints in the comments I thought it might be good to post a complete solution. Try this:

```
static IObservable<int> GetNumbers() =>
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Select(i => (int)i + 1)
        .Do(i => Console.WriteLine($"Producing {i}"))
        .Take(10);

static Task LogNumbers(IObservable<int> observable) =>
    observable
        .Do(i => Console.WriteLine($"Consuming {i}"))
        .ToArray()
        .ToTask();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LogNumbers(GetNumbers()).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Or, even more cleanly:

```
static IObservable<int> GetNumbers() =>
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Select(i => (int)i + 1)
        .Do(i => Console.WriteLine($"Producing {i}"))
        .Take(10);

static IObservable<int> LogNumbers(IObservable<int> observable) =>
    observable
        .Do(i => Console.WriteLine($"Consuming {i}"));

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await LogNumbers(GetNumbers());
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You can `await` observables directly.

Comment: Probably a better return type for the method `LogNumbers` instead of `Task` is `Task<int[]>` (regarding the first example).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes, agreed. I was trying to keep the OP's signature, but you are spot on.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity that's really useful. I suppose this `Observable.Interval(...)` can be used to publish metrics on a regular schedule or do some kind of polling of a web service, etc., right?

Comment: @Steztric - Yes, it's the equivalent of a `Timer`. It sends a value periodically.